# Python 2.6.6: unable to extract text from direct children of the current element

Tags: xml, python-2.x, elementtree

I'm following along [ElementTree tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) and I get mostly the same results when working with the sample XML provided there, but I get unexpected results when using my own XML file.

For example, I'm trying to extract text from all XML tags named `marketCode`. My sample XML file:

```
<process_config>

    <input name="dataIn">
        <filePattern>
            <marketCode>nyse</marketCode>
            <midfix/>
            <format>csv</format>
        </filePattern>
    </input>

    <input name="brokerIn">
        <filePattern>
            <marketCode>lse</marketCode>
            <midfix>.CBOENL</midfix>
            <format>csv</format>
        </filePattern>
    </input>

</process_config>
```

I use the following code to extract the data:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET, sys, os


my_file = 'test.xml'

tree = ET.parse(my_file)
root = tree.getroot()

for filePattern in root.findall('filePattern'):
    marketCode = filePattern.find('marketCode').text
    
    print(marketCode)
```

When I run the above code, I get an empty output. The expected output is as such:

```
nyse
lse
```

What might be wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filePattern` is not a direct child of the root element.

This works: `root.findall('.//filePattern')`. This also works: `root.findall('input/filePattern')`.